# How do I use the Sylius currency importer for my configured currencies?

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I have a number of currencies setup with my Sylius install (v0.14), and I have added an api key within my parameters.yml for open exchange rates.

When running the console command:

```
./app/console sylius:currency:import openexchangerates
```

I see that the exchange rates for my currencies are added to a table named 'sylius_exchange_rate', however the website itself (admin area and front end) seems to use the exchange rate set in 'sylius_currency' table field 'exchange_rate'.

Is this done on purpose so that I can control the import of the exchange rates myself (e.g. modify the console command to import the rates into the sylius_currency table), or is this simply missing logic?

I cannot find any documentation about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Sylius has dropped this feature ([github commit](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/commit/379ac56de96893d1db53dd636863ba38937bc2c0)).

On v0.14, there is another command that may do the job :
sylius:currency:update